# Completely blind SQL injection column enumeration?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I'm doing a school project about webapp security and vulnerabilities, and for that i've made my own **very simple** website with a login and a search bar.

Now, i've made the login silent on purpose, while the search bar shows output on SQL injections. So for demonstration purposes I would like to do a time-based completely blind SQL injection attack on the login... But i'm a bit stuck.

I have no idea how I can enumerate how many columns are in the table for the login query, in a time-based situation:

`SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='' AND cPWD='';`

I cannot do ORDER BY n;#, since I get absolutely no error output when something goes wrong. The only way I can get any indication is through SLEEP() or BENCHMARK().

But I cannot put ORDER BY into a SELECT IF() statement. So how can I find out how many columns exist? (it makes unions impossible for me).

Thank you!

**EDIT: It might be worth mentioning, the site is very unsecure on purpose (doesn't use mysqli, just mysql). Since it is just for demonstration**

Comment: Is it a database restricted to different per-user views? First thing I would try is `SHOW TABLES;` and then `DESCRIBE <table_name>;`, just to see which things I have access to (and, if I'm lucky, table structures).

Comment: @AlejandroIván That won't work. This is **completely** blind SQL injection, meaning the only way for me to see anything is to see how long queries take to complete. The page doesn't change upon error at all.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found an answer to my own question:

Instead of using ORDER BY, I used SELECT and bruteforced my way to see how many columns existed:

`SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='' AND cPWD='';`

Can be enumerated in the dark by doing:

`SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cMAIL='' UNION SELECT null,null,null AND SLEEP(5);# AND cPWD=''`

You just keep adding more nulls to the select until the database sleeps for 5 seconds. Then you know how many columns are in the given table.

Hope this can help someone else.